# jQuery select relative child element inside li tag

Tags: jquery, hover, html-lists, children

I'm kind of a jQuery newbie so bear with me on this.

I'm trying to use jQuery to fadeIn an h6 tag on hover inside of an anchor which is inside of a list item, but IE won't recognize that my cursor is hovering over the anchor because the list item is on top of it in the markup. It works in every other browser, but not IE9 and below.

Here's the markup to give better clarity:  I've got a list of portfolio thumbnails with HTML as follows:

```
<ul class="portfolio">
 <li>
  <span class="top-right-corner"></span>
  <span class="bottom-left-corner"></span>
  <a class="popup" href="#interact"><h6>Interact Live</h6></a>
  <img alt="Interact Live" src="images/interact-thumb.jpg" width="529" height="260" />
 </li>
</ul>
```

The CSS is as follows for this:

```
.portfolio {
display:inline-block;
overflow:visible;
margin-bottom:40px;
}

.portfolio li {
float:left;
z-index:1;
margin-right:35px;
margin-bottom:58px;
position:relative;
}

.portfolio li.right {
margin-right:0;
}

.portfolio li a {
display:block;
cursor:pointer;
border:1px solid #57bfe6;
position:absolute;
width:99.7%;
height:99.5%;
top:0;
z-index:9;
left:0;
text-decoration:none;
}

.portfolio li a h6 {
background:rgba(3,85,117,0.9);
box-shadow:0 0 40px 30px #003e57 inset;
font-size:66px;
color:#ddf6ff;
text-align:center;
padding-top:100px;
height:163px;
width:99.6%;
}

.portfolio li img {
display:block;
border:3px solid #023d53;
}

.top-right-corner {
background:url('images/about-icons.png') no-repeat -38px -198px;
height:45px;
width:45px;
position:absolute;
top:-10px;
right:-10px;
z-index:10;
}

.bottom-left-corner {
background:url('images/about-icons.png') no-repeat -32px -254px;
height:45px;
width:45px;
position:absolute;
bottom:-10px;
left:-10px;
z-index:10;
}
```

The jQuery to fade in the h6 tag seems problematic, and I'm not sure how to fix this correctly for IE:

```
  $(".portfolio li a h6").hide();
  $(".portfolio li a").hover(function(){
    $(this).children("h6").fadeIn();
  });
  $(".portfolio li a").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).children("h6").fadeOut();
  });
```

It seems like IE doesn't recognize that .portfolio li a is being hovered in the first place, it instead thinks .portfolio li is being hovered instead of .portfolio li a. Is there a way to get this to work correctly?

Comment: See my Answer, Hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
$(".portfolio li a").hide();
$(".portfolio li").hover(function(){
    $(this).children("a").stop(true, true).fadeIn();
},function() {
    $(this).children("a").stop(true, true).fadeOut();
});
```

### [SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YN2gt/)

Comment: @nairbdes: Usted es bienvenido

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be related to the CSS, when the only element within the anchor is hidden hovering over it doesn't make sense, please note that `hover` method should be used in this way:

```
$(".portfolio li").hover(function(){
      $(this).find("h6").fadeIn();
   },function() {
      $(this).find("h6").fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: Hmm, same issue, only IE won't show the h6 tag when I hover over the li tag parent.

Comment: I have the a tag set to position absolute with a defined width and height, so that if the h6 tag is hidden, the a tag should still be there right?

Comment: @nairbdes Yes, but I'm not sure about IE.

Comment: Please feel free to visit the website I provided in IE to see the issue first-hand. I appreciate the help!

Comment: @nairbdes See my Answer, Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: @nairbdes I'm sorry bro, I'm on mac.